# Values for a new AC adapter, and not OEM lock

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I have two questions

The first one it's about buying a new AC adapter for my Dell laptop the specs for the original one and the one i've found are this

**ORIGINAL ->** INPUT: 100-240V **1.6A** 50-60Hz / OUTPUT: 19.5V 3.34A / 65w / PA-12 FAMILY - MODEL: LA65NS2-01

**NEW ->** INPUT: 100-240V **1.5A** 50-60Hz / OUTPUT: 19.5V 3.34A / 65W / PA-12 FAMILY - MODEL: LA65NS1-00

As you might notice, everything is the same except for the input amperage, my question is there is a problem with that, this will harm my laptop in some way? or the only specs that really matter are the output ones?

The second problem I have is since my laptop is from Dell, in some webpages people says that almost every non OEM accesories, like AC adapters, batteries, etc. doesn't work, for example, if I connect a new AC adapter and it is not from Dell this will work but will no charge my battery at all, and for what I have been reading, AC adapter come with something than allows the computer recognize that it's not OEM, and this is probably what will happen... The question is, there is some way that I can bypass this restiction? maybe BIOS configuation or something?

By the way my laptop it's a Dell Inspiron 14' series 5000 model 5447

Thanks in advance

Comment: "maybe BIOS configuation or something?" The reports you read made no mention of that which means you should assume that option doesn't exist.  If it was that easy then those reports you read wouldn't exist...

Comment: There is a similar thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1160735/stop-dell-from-throttling-cpu-with-power-adapter)

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one question. You can ask separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

The adapter you mention will work fine. When it comes to Dell adapters, at the time of this writing, there are only a couple of types of plugs they use. If the adapter is made for Dell and the plug matches, the only important number is that the new adapter has a wattage rating greater equal to or greater than that which the laptop requires.

It is true that the laptop communicates with the power adapter via the center pin. The adapter will report to the laptop what power capabilities it has. The laptop can use this information to recognize if it is a compatible adapter.

As long as the adapter identifies itself as for Dell, then it should be fine. However, as cheap as you can get "genuine" Dell adapters online I would go that route. I only purchase adapters that say "Dell" on them. Although I'm pretty confident some of these are knock offs. But I simply don't buy garbage $10 universal or "compatible" adapters. Why deal with the trouble?  That $10 adapter could cost you hundreds of dollars of laptop if it overvolts or surges the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

No problem whatsoever.

For a replacement adapter to power your device correctly, the following things 2 must be met:

- identical output voltage
- current equal or higher than original

And of course, for the input it'll have to be same mainline spec (110/120 xor 220/240) if it's not universal like the ones you listed. The 1.5 vs 1.6 A in your case means just a difference in power consumption.

Comment: thnks, i'm actually waiting for the arrival of my new adapter!