Fresh clean Windows 10 installation is always throttling CPU to 10% llimit
Fresh Windows 10 installation on my DELL M6800 with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4930MX CPU @ 3.00GHz is always throtlling it to 10%  making it almost unusable.
I have tried different options like Group Poilicy, Performance setting, etc but no use, it always stays at 10%, other devices like Network, and dsisk are all performing as expected but overall performance gets limited by CPU speed.
No matter what i present it as a workload it never goes beyond 10% performance.
On the same machine when i run linux from the dual boot configuration  everything runs perfectly (CPU performs at full speed), also a Windows installation as a VirtualBox VM on the linux hosts performs at full frequency. Make me sure that there is no hardware problem.
Please help me.
PS: Drivers are all latest from the DELL, Windows updates are all uptodate.

long shot, but since you wrote "etc." we have to guess. check power config settings for a heat related setting and set it to "fan first, then throttle" the wording may be different. Do this for both plugged and unplugged. Also, check this thread regarding BD PROCHOT. Probably not the issue since you say linux is OK but worth a check. And then see if there is a speedstep and/or speed shift BIOS setting and turn them both off as a test: https://superuser.com/questions/1160735/stop-dell-from-throttling-cpu-with-power-adapter

This sounds like a BIOS issue if Windows is the only thing that is not performing well when installed. To be sure that you have no issues with your BIOS, I would confirm that they are the latest and have no reported issues with Windows 10.
You can check your Bios a few ways:
Through PowerShell
Get-WmiObject win32_bios

PowerShell Output
Through Bash
sudo dmidecode | less

Sample Output
BIOS Information
        Vendor: Dell Inc.
        Version: A02
        Release Date: 02/03/2010
        Address: 0xF0000
        Runtime Size: 64 kB
        ROM Size: 2112 kB
        Characteristics:
                ISA is supported
                PCI is supported
                PC Card (PCMCIA) is supported
                PNP is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                3.5"/720 KB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
                8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
                Serial services are supported (int 14h)
                Printer services are supported (int 17h)
                CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
                ACPI is supported
                USB legacy is supported
                AGP is supported
                Smart battery is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Function key-initiated network boot is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
        BIOS Revision: 0.2
        Firmware Revision: 0.2

Handle 0x0100, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
        Product Name: Precision M6500                 
        Version: Not Specified
        Serial Number: 55Lxxxx
        UUID: 4a2yzzzeC-3500-xxx-yyy-Bzzzzyyy5y
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: Not Specified
        Family:  

 



Compare your output from those commands against the Dell Support database - https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=nr58c&oscode=wt64a&productcode=precision-m6800-workstation
