# New battery not charging

Tags: linux, linux-mint, battery, charging, dell-vostro

after replacing old battery od my notebook, bios complained that there is a problem with battery and linux shows charging, but after hours, there is still 3%. Also, the overal system is somewhat slower, as if the graphics was lagging.

The notebook is Dell Vostro 3550, the new battery is T6 POWER NBDE0120 (9cell, 7800mAh).

Here is upower dump:

`Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
  native-path:          AC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              St 8. leden 2020, 08:51:48 CET (5151 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    online:             yes
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMP
  model:                DELL VXVK20B
  serial:               31802
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              St 8. leden 2020, 10:17:24 CET (15 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    energy:              2,8194 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         86,58 Wh
    energy-full-design:  86,58 Wh
    energy-rate:         0,0111 W
    voltage:             10,638 V
    percentage:          3%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.9.23
  can-suspend:     yes
  can-hibernate:   yes
  on-battery:      no
  on-low-battery:  no
  lid-is-closed:   yes
  lid-is-present:  yes
  is-docked:       yes`

Edit:

There is one thing - when I power on the notebook, there is this message: http://www.laptop-junction.com/toast/content/dell-ac-power-adapter-not-recognized

But I have the same charger as with the previous battery. I was assuming, that previous battery is dead due to the yellow blinking power indicator on notebook, but could it be, that the issue is with the AC charger?

Edit 2:

As the @user1138 suggests, I have tested the notebook with another charger (my is 90W, the other one is 65W) and the result is the same with both bateries: the PSU is OK. But it is still confusing, why the BIOS is showing 0W charger when the new battery is used?

Edit 3:
So finally I have managed to get tha battery charging - @user1138 has pointed me the right direction, so big thanks to you @user1138. The problem was however not in the charger itself, but rather in the detection of the charger. What I have done to solve this problem:
- reset BIOS settings to the factory defaults - dont know, if this helps, because nothing changed after this step, even after restarting the notebook, but maybe it could be somehow important
- when the OS botts up, I have unplugged the charger from the notebook for several seconds, and then plugged it back - after that, it immediately starts to charge the battery and after restart I have checked BIOS that now it sees the charger (90 W) - the unplug / plug needs to be done when the powered on, otherwise the charge is not detected.

Comment: Seems like the new battery is either unsuitable or DOA (dead on arrival).

Comment: Thank you @harrymc, is there a way how to tell, if the is unsuitable or DOA. According to the info on the e-shop page for this battery, Vostro 3550 is amongs the supported notebooks.

Comment: I'd have my money on it being a bung ID Chip in your power supply - a common 'feature' on Dell Lappy PSU's - try working through some of these answers to isolate/fix the issue. PS - an easy test, find somebody else with a Dell and swap PSU's

Comment: And the link - https://superuser.com/questions/442772/workaround-for-dell-power-supply-not-recognised-issue