# Dell "Power supply not recognised" GRUB solution not working

Tags: power-supply, dell

I have the same problem as this guy
[Workaround for Dell "Power supply not recognised" issue](https://superuser.com/questions/442772/workaround-for-dell-power-supply-not-recognised-issue)

But the solution to add `processor.ignore_ppc=1` did nothing. What steps would you suggest me to take in order to debug this issue?

The machine i've got is a refurbished Dell Optiplex 7050 micro and it come with 65W Dell HA65NS5-00 power supply

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details about your machine.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was the middle pin in the charger connector.

It was bent and I couldn't plug it all the way in.

Fixing the pin with the screwdriver and plugging it all the way in solved the issue.